# $setValidity not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a condition where if user enters either contact number or email form should be considered as valid, to make this work I tried to use $setValidity but is not working, below is my code:

```
if($scope.contact.contactNumber || $scope.contact.email) {
    $scope.addContactForm.contactNumber.$setValidity('required', false);
    $scope.addContactForm.email.$setValidity('required', false);

    // In console it will show invalid as true & valid as false
    console.log('Scope:', $scope.addContactForm);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are doing it wrong. You should pass true as second argument if you want to set field to valid state. Read [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Below is example how to use $setValidity correctly.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function () {
  this.setValid = () => {
    this.form.contactNumber.$setValidity('required', true);
    this.form.email.$setValidity('required', true);
  };
  
  this.setInvalid = () => {
    this.form.contactNumber.$setValidity('required', false);
    this.form.email.$setValidity('required', false);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Example">
  <form name="Example.form">
    <input type="text" name="contactNumber" ng-model="contactNumber" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email" require>
  </form>
  <br>
  $invalid = {{Example.form.$invalid}}, $valid = {{Example.form.$valid}}<br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Example.setValid()">set valid</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Example.setInvalid()">set invalid</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I had already tried setting it to true as well but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this if some one facing same issue it might helpful. I tried passing null it started working instead of false.

```
    $scope.addContactForm.contactNumber.$setValidity('required', false);
```

I hope it will helpfull for someone